# union of countable many positive sets has a positive signed measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $P_{1},P_{2},....$ be positive sets for $\nu$, then $P=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}
^{\infty}P_{n}$ is a postive set for $\nu$

Proof:
Let $Q_{1}=P_{1},Q_{2}=P_{2}\setminus P_{1}$....$Q_{n}=P_{n}\setminus\displaystyle\bigcup_{j=1}^{n-1}P_{j}$ So all $Q_{n}'s$ are disjoint and $P=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}Q_{j}$ since $Q_{j}\subset P_{j}$ for each $j$ then each $Q_{j}$ is postivie set for $\nu$.

So now we want to show that any subset of $P$ is positive for $\nu$.

let$ E\subset P$ then $\nu(E\cap Q_{n})>0$ and $\nu(E)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\nu(E\cap Q_{j})\ge 0$

how do we get the last line? why is  $\nu(E\cap Q_{n})>0$ is it because $Q_{n}$ is positivie for arbitrary $n$ and $E$ is a measurable set and a measure of any set is non-negative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\nu(E\cap Q_n)>0$ in the last line clearly cannot be guaranteed without further information on $E$. For example, if $E$ is empty, then $\nu(E\cap Q_n)=0$. I'm pretty sure it's a typo.

The proof can be expanded on as follows. Let $E\subseteq P$ be a *measurable* set. Then, $$E=E\cap P=E\cap\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} Q_j\right)=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} (E\cap Q_j).$$ Since the $Q_j$'s are disjoint, so are the $E\cap Q_j$'s, so that $$\nu(E)=\nu\left(\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} (E\cap Q_j)\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\nu(E\cap Q_j)\geq0,$$ where the inequality follows from the fact that $Q_j$ is a positive set for $\nu$ for all $j$ and $E\cap Q_j\subseteq Q_j$, so that $\nu(E\cap Q_j)\geq0$ for all $j$.

Comment: brilliant, thank you!

Comment: @HeidiE My pleasure!